# Как создать run файл из скомпилированной программы?

Tags: c++, linux

Как сделать .run файл из скомпилированной(или из исходников) программы на С++? мне нужно именно сценарий shell (application/x-shellscript) инкапсулировать во внутрь скрипта. Программа написана на Qt.

Comment: просто при компиляции из исходников добавьте расшиерение и все. Типа: gcc -o 1.run 1.cpp

Comment: Да спасибо, но как сделать из него Сценарий shell (application/x-shellscript)

Comment: этого я не знаю, но лучше отредактируйте ваш вопрос, если хотите, чтобы на него был дан ответ

Comment: В скрипте одной строкой запустить этот бинарник? Или вы хотите инкапсулировать бинарник внутрь скрипта?

Comment: Во внутрь скрипта.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону shell archive.

Comment: Да это я и без вас понял. Я не могу найти толковый материал по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

вот вам **самое** примитивное решение. то, что имеется, например, в пакете [makeself](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/makeself), является лишь «более расширенной, более улучшенной, более совместимой и более многословной» версией.

---

базовый скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh

# получаем смещение от начала скрипта до присоединённого к нему файла
offset=$(sed -e '/^###начало файла$/q' "$0" | wc -c)
# сохраняем всё, начиная с полученного смещения, в файл output.file
dd if="$0" skip=1 ibs=$offset 2>/dev/null > output.file
# делаем что надо с полученным output.file

exit # это обязательно, иначе оболочка попытается интерпретировать то, что ниже
###начало файла
```

получение итогового файла:

```
$ cat базовый.скрипт присоединяемый.файл > run
```

---

если его запустить:

```
$ sh run
```

то в текущем каталоге появится файл output.file, содержимое которого идентично присоединённому файлу.

вместо просто сохранения (или в дополнение к нему) вы можете вставить в базовый скрипт любую необходимую вам функциональность.