# инсталляшка в bash-скрипте

Tags: bash

как вставить в скрипт исполняемый файл и потом, при запуске скрипта, вывести из скрипта этот файл и запустить его?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828173/178576

Comment: если речь идет о вирусописательстве, то такие финты антивирусные пакеты отлавливают)

Comment: Александр! Спасибо! попробую решить проблему по предложенному Вами варианту

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы бинарный файл вставить в текстовый документ со скриптом нужно избавиться от бинарной сущности файла (инсталяшки в вопросе), для этого его нужно конвертировать в строку. Для этой цели подойдет утилита **base64** (обычно поставляется в составе дистрибутива linux)

Тогда алгоритм работы по созданию скрипта с интегрированным инсталлером будет следующий:

1. Конвертируем инсталляшку в текстовый документ при помощи **base64**
2. Содержимое полученного текстового документа заносим в переменную внутри bash скрипта
3. Во время исполнения bash-скрипта сделать сохранение содержимого созданной переменной в отдельный файл
4. Конвертирование полученного файла обратно в бинарный при помощи той же утилиты **base64**
5. Назначение полученному файлу нужных прав на исполнение при помощи утилиты  chmod
6. Запуск из скрипта полученного файла с нужными параметрами

Comment: если инсталляшка сильно большая, то такой способ не поможет (скорее всего любой способ тогда не поможет)

Comment: Сабир! Это Вариант! Спасибо. 
Просто видел вот такое исполнение https://svnclient.oxygenxml.com/InstData/Linux64/VM/syncroSVNClient-64bit.sh
Правда не понял как он работает :-(
Там нет Base64.
Может поможете разобраться?

Comment: там в любом случае должно и пользоваться что-то такое что позволит бинарные данные представить в виде текста, а дальше в скрипте с текстом можно делать что хочешь